# apachectl not working in shell script

Tags: shell

Here is a problem with my shell script.Please help to solve this.

If I type in terminal like this,

> apachectl -S | awk '{if ($4 == "example.abc.uws") print $4;}

It will give output `example.abc.uws`.(This is a url i have configured in Apache.)

But if I store `example.abc.uws` into a variable and given with `apachectl` command like this,

> var=example.abc.uws
>   apachectl -S | awk '{if ($4 == $var) print $4;}

Then, it will not give any output.

Please help with this problem.I think there might be some issues with `$servername` given with the `apachectl` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var=example.abc.uws
apachectl -S | awk -v x="$var" '{if ($4 == x) print $4;}
```